# How can I remove the "VS Code" widget from the issue layout on Jira?

Tags: jira

Atlassian has added a "VS Code" widget (labelled "Start work in VS Code") to the issue layout in Jira.

[image]

This widget, unlike the other issue layout elements, is not included in the elements that we can configure via the "[Default Issue Screen](https://masschallenge.atlassian.net/plugins/servlet/project-config/%5BPROJECT_NAME%5D/issuelayout?screenId=10000)". How can we remove this from the issue view?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this was an "experiment" that Atlassian mistakenly rolled out to all users. Atlassian has addressed this issue by reverting the change that rolled this out to all users.

[Ticket](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/API-343)

[Comment explaining resolution](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/API-343?focusedCommentId=2593589&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-2593589)